# D3: Highlighting Parts of Path on Mouseover in Line Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am wondering if it is possible to have a d3 line graph in which a draggable window highlights or changes the color of only the parts of a line (path) that are in the window.

Here is an image that [exemplifies the use case](http://forums.infragistics.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files/265/8540.Untitled.png)

I can alter the entire line or break the line up into parts, but I'm wondering if it is possible to simply alter each point on the path that is in the window.

How would I be able to access the points in the path in order to alter them? From there I think I would be able to alter them. it's a matter of grabbing their attributes.

Comment: Do you also have a explicit case for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

1. Render whole path twice, once normal and once highlighted
2. Use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking) on the highlighted version
3. Dynamically change used clipPath to be in the shape of highlighted rectangle.

Comment: Thank you. But I tried using clippath and for some reason it doesn't actually mask the underlying line https://jsfiddle.net/850bae9m/

Comment: You are producing wrong markup. The rectangle must be drawn under svg > defs > clipPath(id=window) and the line must have attr clip-path="url(#window)". See my link above and compare that with the DOM tree that your code is producing.

Answer (score 1):

What you have in your image is not a *window* that changes the path's colour. That is just a regular rectangle with an opacity smaller than 1.

However, I'd like to drop my two cents mentioning something that is normally ignored: [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Referenz/mix-blend-mode).

It's very difficult getting the exact colours you want to change with `mix-blend-mode`, but it is a funny feature and, the most important, you don't have to *break* the path.

Have a look at this demo, dragging the rectangular "window". It highlights the green path turning it into a red path:

```js
var data = d3.range(50).map(() => [Math.random() * 300, Math.random() * 150]);

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var path = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.line().curve(d3.curveBasis)(data))
  .style("stroke", "green")
  .style("stroke-width", "3px")
  .style("fill", "none");

var backRect = svg.append("rect")
  .datum({
    x: 100,
    y: 50
  })
  .attr("x", d => d.x)
  .attr("y", d => d.y)
  .attr("width", 60)
  .attr("height", 40)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "black");

var rect = svg.append("rect")
  .datum({
    x: 100,
    y: 50
  })
  .attr("x", d => d.x)
  .attr("y", d => d.y)
  .attr("width", 60)
  .attr("height", 40)
  .attr("cursor", "pointer")
  .style("fill", "red")
  .style("mix-blend-mode", "hue")
  .call(d3.drag().on("drag", function(d) {
    rect.attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)
      .attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y);
    backRect.attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)
      .attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y)
  }))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. This seems to work a bit. I'm having trouble getting it to be just a darker or lighter version of the path color behind it and I don't understand how the rest of the chart is managing to stay white and only the path is affected but will keep playing with it. Thanks